# Passing character and data.frame arguments to a function using do.call()

Tags: r, function, do.call, r-lavaan

I don't know if I'm being an idiot, but I'm trying to pass arguments to the lavaan cfa() function using do.call(). I've done this successfully with other functions but in this case the arguments are mixed - i.e. the first is a character string, the second a data.frame, and the third a character string again. Take this simple example:

```
require(lavaan)

#simulating data
t <- rnorm(100,0,.8)
y1 <- t + rnorm(100,0,.2)
y2 <- t + rnorm(100,0,.2)
y3 <- t + rnorm(100,0,.2)
g <- c(0,1)
data <- data.frame(y1,y2,y3,g)

#setting up the lavaan model
model <- 'f1 =~ y1 + y2 + y3'
```

Now simply using these arguments works fine

```
cfa(model,data,group='g')
```

But when I try to use the do.call()

```
args <- list(model=model,data=data,group='g')
do.call(cfa,args)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in as.character(mc[[1L]]) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I tried using substitute(), any combination of quotation marks and the quote-Argument of do.call() but all to no avail. Because I want to use this for a sort-of mini-package I want to avoid using any other packages and would rather only use base functions. Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best, Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do.call` expects its first argument to be the 'name' of the function. Usually it works if this is entered as an R symbol (an expression without quotes) or expressed as a single element character value. In this case `cfa` is a wrapper for `lavaan` and the function name is converted to a list element named 'model.type' which succeeds when it is a character value but not when it is an R symbol-name of a function.

```
> do.call('cfa',args)
lavaan (0.5-15) converged normally after  56 iterations

  Number of observations per group         
  0                                                 50
  1                                                 50

  Estimator                                         ML
  Minimum Function Test Statistic                0.000
  Degrees of freedom                                 0
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Chi-square for each group:

  0                                              0.000
  1                                              0.000
```

Comment: `do.call()` will  actually take a name or a symbol. The problem is that `cfa` does `mc <- match.call()` and then coerces the first element of `mc` to a character. (I'm really not sure why the authors do that, and as this question shows, they probably shouldn't). In any case, when you do  `do.call(cfa, ...)`, `cfa` is first replaced with its value, a function definition, before the conversion to character. That's what's causing the problem.

Comment: This does seem to get it to work but the documentation for do.call says `either a function or a non-empty character string naming the function to be called.` when describing the 'what' parameter. It seems the issue is more with the cfa function and the way it handles things.

Comment: -1 as the one and only sentence in this answer is plain wrong (even if it does get the job done). @JoshO'Brien you should put that in an answer imo - as that's the actual answer.

Comment: @eddi -- Thanks, but I'm sure DWin will edit the answer when he gets back, and I'm happy not to clutter this up with a second answer of my own.

Comment: Thank you both for the solution and the explanation. I think that I'll be using do.call(lavaan,args) with the additional model.type='cfa' argument so I can handle other model types more flexibly and circumvent the confusion that led to my asking this question.